# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cc' : return code '0x1'

Tags: c, compiler-errors, makefile

I use windows 10 and am trying to compile a downloaded project using a make file. I enter:

```
`nmake -f Makefile'
```

in the appropriate directory and get error:

```
'cc -03 -o lsd lsd_cmd.c -lm
'cc' is not recognized as an internal or external comand, operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cc' : return code 'ox1'
Stop.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think maybe it is because it cant find a c compiler?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Did you install a C compiler at all? As contained in MinGW or CygWin?

Comment: Either install a c compiler or update your PATH to point to the location of your compiler

Comment: I'm guessing you are building [LSD](https://github.com/theWorldCreator/LSD). It's [Makefile](https://github.com/theWorldCreator/LSD/blob/master/Makefile) uses commands that usually work on a Unix type system such as Linux. It will probably work in a MinGW or CygWin environment on Windows.

Comment: You could probably set up an empty command line project in Visual Studio easily enough. The main executable `lsd.exe` only needs a couple of source files in the project - `lsd.c` and `lsd_cmd.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says exactly what the problem is.

`'cc' is not recognized as an internal or external comand, operable program or batch file.`

cc would be a compiler, and Windows cannot find it. You either

a) Don't have a C compiler

b) cc does not point to your C compiler

If (a), download a C compiler. MinGW or Cygwin should work. If (b), you can try changing the makefile from 'cc' to whatever your C compiler's name is (gcc, for example), adding the C compiler to the system path, and/or creating a symlink to point 'cc' to your C compiler.