# 'cl' : Return Code 0x1 during make file build

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

I downloaded a solution file from PTC (Creo Parametric) for their toolkit.

They have a user guide to follow, linked below:
http://support.ptc.com/WCMS/files/172149/en/creo4_m010_Toolkit_GSG.pdf

The solution file is designed for visual studio 2015 (I am using 2017).

When I build the makefile I get the following errors:

U1077 'cl' : return code '0x1'

&

MSB3073 The command "name /f make_install dll" exited with code 2.

I am trying to figure out, what does 'cl' : return code '0x1' truly mean in this exact context?

At this stage, PTC supposedly handed everything over on a silver platter.

I did see these posts:
[NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cc' : return code '0x1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042234/nmake-fatal-error-u1077-cc-return-code-0x1)
-seems to be compiler related, but I am using Visual Studio so this should be a mute point

[fatal error U1077: 'cl' : return code '0x1' new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107587/fatal-error-u1077-cl-return-code-0x1-new)
-The PTC user guide specifically tells me to simply load Visual Studio and open the solution file, define the load point path, and build.

The only thing I had to do special was define the following in the makefile they provided:

```
# PROTOOL_SRC = ../../../..
PROTOOL_SRC = C:/PTC/CREO4~1.0/M070/COMMON~1/PROTOO~1
```

Basically they need you to edit the makefile to define the directory of where the toolkit dependencies are installed.

Here is the part of the make file where I define PROTOOL_SRC and the compiler flags below, where 'cl' is.

```
# Pro/Toolkit Source & Machine Loadpoint  (EXTERNAL USE - DEFAULT)
# PROTOOL_SRC = ../../../..
PROTOOL_SRC = C:/PTC/CREO4~1.0/M070/COMMON~1/PROTOO~1
PROTOOL_SYS = $(PROTOOL_SRC)/$(PRO_MACHINE_TYPE)

# Pro/Toolkit Source & Machine Loadpoint  (PTC INTERNAL USE)
#PROTOOL_SRC = $(PTCSRC)/protoolkit
#PROTOOL_SYS = $(PTCSYS)

ICU_PATH = $(PROTOOL_SYS)/obj

# Include File Paths
INCS = -I. -I$(PROTOOL_SRC)/protk_appls/includes       
-I$(PROTOOL_SRC)/includes 

# Compiler Flags
CC = cl
MACH = -DPRO_MACHINE=36 -DPRO_OS=4
CCFLAGS = -c -GS -fp:precise -D_WSTDIO_DEFINED -D_USING_V110_SDK71_
CFLAGS = $(CCFLAGS) $(INCS) $(MACH)
```

So, knowing all of this.. why would the makefile error 'cl' : return code '0x1' exist?
Is there something I need to set in my Visual Studio 2017 Environment?

Comment: So I determined that the compiler doesn’t know what “cl” is.  In the make file log, it states that cl is not a recognizable command.  This leaves me to discovering something called vcvarsall.bat.  I need to figure out how to incorporate this in the VS 2017 environment.  On a side note, I can open the developer command prompt and type “cl” and I get a response for options.  So I am assuming I do have cl.exe

Comment: did you try to put cl.exe instead of cl ?